# What is the difference between statistics.stdev() & numpy.std() and which is more precise?

Tags: numpy, statistics, std, stdev

I used this dataset:

```
lst = [81922.00557103065, 82887.70053475935, 80413.01627033792,
       81708.86075949368, 82997.38219895288, 84641.50943396226,
       81929.82456140351, 82632.24181360201, 77667.98418972333,
       73726.47427854454, 86113.2075471698, 83232.98429319372,
       79866.66666666667, 83833.74689826302, 81943.06930693069,
       77898.64029666255, 77401.47783251232, 80607.59493670886,
       78384.5126835781, 82608.69565217392, 80824.8730964467,
       84163.70106761566, 74887.38738738738
       ]
```

Then `statistics.stdev(lst)` is 3096.28 and `numpy.std(lst)` is 3028.23. The difference is about 2.2%.

Comment: To get the same value as `statistics.stddev(lst)` with NumPy, use `numpy.std(lst, ddof=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**They are calculating two slightly different things.**

The standard deviation is the square root of the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance). NumPy is using the sample variance, whereas `statistics` is adjusting this with [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction). This uses N – 1 instead of N in the calculation of the variance:

```py
arr = np.array(lst)
var_ordinary = np.sum(abs(arr - arr.mean())**2) / arr.size
var_bessel = np.sum(np.abs(arr - arr.mean())**2) / (arr.size - 1)
```

From [the `statistics` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.variance):

> This is the sample variance s² with Bessel’s correction, also known as variance with N-1 degrees of freedom. Provided that the data points are representative (e.g. independent and identically distributed), the result should be an unbiased estimate of the true population variance.